# iOS 9 Universal Links - no parameters recieved

Tags: objective-c, ios9, ios-universal-links

Using the new iOS 9 feature - Universal links, from my understanding, is supposed top open my app whenever a specific domain is opened in browser (or other apps?). I have gone through the documentation and through this [guide](https://blog.branch.io/how-to-setup-universal-links-to-deep-link-on-apple-ios-9).

However, when the app opens I do not receive the parameter that is meant to help me open the correct page for the user to view....

I would share the code I'm using, but it's quite a big infrastructure and not really a couple of lines of code (server side JSON, plist rows and some IDs on the developer portal).

Anyone encountered it and could give me a hand here, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Branch guide you linked to (full disclosure: I work with the Branch team) unfortunately doesn't cover a rather important step: *what to do after your app opens*. Which is exactly the issue you're encountering :). But the good news is you've already done the hard part with all the server and entitlement config.

What you need to complete the loop is a [`continueUserActivity` handler](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler:) in your **AppDelegate.m** file. This will pass you a [`webpageURL` property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUserActivity_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSUserActivity/webpageURL) containing the actual URL of the Universal Link that opened your app, which you can then parse and use for routing. It'll look something like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *))restorationHandler {
    if ([userActivity.activityType isEqualToString:NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb]) {
     NSString *myUrl = [userActivity.webpageURL absoluteString];
        // parse URL string or access query params
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Also, when testing keep in mind that Universal Links unfortunately *don't* work everywhere yet:

[image]

P.S., gotta ask...since you found the Branch blog already, had you considered using the service to handle the link routing for you? It can definitely help simplify things!

Comment: This answer was on point, thank you. Yes we have considered it but we prefer leaving the control in our hands.

Comment: @user3778974 definitely understand. Feel free to drop [our support](https://support.branch.io) a note anyway if you run into any issues with redirects. We've dealt with hundreds of edge cases so happy to provide advice even if you're not on the Branch SDK!